# How to check whether rows have a common value in one column but a different value in another

Tags: mysql

I have a simple SQL table with the following columns: id, path, hash and iNode which correspond to values for multiple files in an Apple Time Capsule.

I am trying to assert whether some files have:

- Same iNode number but different hash;
- Same hash but different iNode number. I've managed to find an example of this case so no longer an issue.

I'm looking for a query to identify these cases. The query is probably the same but with inverted variables. I need to verify this and cannot simply rely on the fact that iNodes are supposed to be unique. What query can I use?

Comment: Please don't describe your data but show some example data that expresses what you are trying to do

Comment: use `group by` query on either fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the same iNode number but different hash:

```
select iNode
from yourtable
group by iNode
having count(distinct hash)>1
```

And the same other way around:

```
select hash 
from yourtable
group by hash
having count(distinct iNode)>1
```

Comment: Good point, no I am not :) Anything else other than uptick and vote for the answer?